# How to store csv file content and filenames from a directory in an array in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to store the filenames in an array and read the csv files using pd.read_csv() and store that into an array.
All the csv files are stored in a folder called '/Data'
I'm trying this in jupyter notebook for your reference
Thank u in advance

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []
stock_name = []
path="/'''/Data"
filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.csv")
for filename in filenames:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0))
    stock_name.append(filename)
print(dataframes)
```

When I do print(dataframes) or print(stock_name), I seem to be getting an empty array as such [ ]

Comment: If check `print (filenames)` it return empty list?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i am understanding the question correctly, but this is what i have user to import python files.

```
from os import walk    
    
blueprint_dirnames = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk("flasksite/Blueprints"):
    blueprint_dirnames.extend(dirnames)
    break

print(blueprint_dirnames)
    
for lib in blueprint_dirnames:
   print(lib)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []
stock_name = []
path = "/Data/*.csv"
filenames = glob.glob(path)
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
    dataframes.append(df)
    stock_name.append(filename)
print(dataframes)
print(stock_name)
```